# Comparing floats in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to compare numbers in KDB.

If I do:

```
exp 0.6931472
```

I get `2f` as a response.

If I do `(exp 0.6931472) = 2`, I get `0b` when I expect `1b`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2f that is initially returned does not mean exactly 2f, and adjusting the precision showcases this.

```
q)\P 10
q)exp 0.6931472
2.000000039
```

You can use `-P` command line arg to set precision within the session, which should make things clearer.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/cmdline/#-p-display-precision

Comment: Adding to Seans answer, you shouldn't ever try to compare floats exactly as it's only going to lead you into trouble. It's not an exact science so you can't get exact comparisons. See discussion at https://code.kx.com/q/basics/precision/